# Get email addresses of customers that didn't complete Paypal checkout

Tags: marketing, paypal, payments, payment-gateway

As a webmaster of a small shop with only one product and a simple Paypal button:

[image]

is it possible to get informations, from Paypal, about the potential customers who clicked on "Buy" **but didn't proceed to a purchase**?

I can imagine that, for confidentiality, their emails will not be available (even if this would be super useful).

On the other hand, I once heard an e-shop owner saying *"When people finally don't complete the payment in the last step, we send them a promotional discount email"*. How do they do this?

Comment: Have you used "retargeting" marketing?   That is showing ads to users after they leave your site as they browse around other sites?   Both Google and Facebook offer those ads.   They are very effective, especially for users that didn't complete purchases.   You have to set attributes with the advertising networks (using JavaScript or a tag manager) as users browse around your site.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Do you have a simple article explaining how it works? Where should I create these ads, by FB / ggl or a third party company?

Comment: You usually want to start with Google and Facebook.  https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2453998?hl=en and https://www.facebook.com/business/learn/facebook-ads-reach-existing-customers   Google has a very large network of sites, but dealing directly with Facebook is the only way to reach folks browsing Facebook.   Here is a guide from HubSpot that looks pretty comprehensive: https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/retargeting-campaigns-beginner-guide

Comment: Oh okay I see, the famous "FB pixel". PS: your comments could be an answer @StephenOstermiller!